# How to overwrite url in local module

Tags: magento-1.7, overrides, configuration

I am overwriting `Mage_Checkout` module to local as `Myshop_Checkout`.I almost did and worked perfect.

And in `Mage_Checkout` i want to change this code,and i dont like to use secure_url.

**1.Mage_Checkout original**

```
<secure_url>
        <wishlist>/wishlist/</wishlist>
</secure_url>
```

To avoid secure url
I edited in core magento like this,

**2.Mage_Checkout edited**

```
<!-- <secure_url>
        <wishlist>/wishlist/</wishlist>
    </secure_url>-->
<wishlist>/wishlist/</wishlist>
```

From above, core magento use secure i want wishlist as normal http://.

Comment: If you do not wish to use SSL at all, why not define the secure url as being http:// instead of https:// - that way you could leave the code as is and also if you chose to use SSL later, it would simply work by editing the secure URL?

Comment: @tecjam i only want to change for this module only.I dont want to change for whole.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Maybe have a look at this: http://blog.goods-pro.com/1792/magento-custom-module-frontend-url-is-forced-to-https-why/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this in the `config.xml` of your module:

```
<config>
    ....
    <frontend>
        <secure_url>
            <wishlist>/some-text-here-that-is-not-an-url/</wishlist>
        </secure_url>
    </frontend>
    ....
</config>
```

And in the `app/etc/modules/Myshop_Checkout.xml` make your module depend on the `Mage_Wishlist` module.
This way, when the config files are merged, the `secure_url/wishlist` tag is overwritten and magento will match your urls against `some-text-here-that-is-not-an-url` instead of `wishlist`. This will always be false, so the wishlist will not be on a secure url anymore.

Comment: i'll give this a try, but i wanna confirm my wish, I just dont want `secure_url` so  i would like to overwrite core magento config to my local.Does your answer solve this?

Comment: not sure I understand. You want only your wishlist page not to be on a secure url? If so, then this answer should solve the problem. Login, register and checkout will still be on a secure page if you have the secure pages enabled. Cloning the config.xml file to the `local` folder may not solve the issue.

Comment: No I want wishlist on secure_url too, but not https:// only http:// routing is needed.

Comment: https means secure...I don't get it. Maybe you should describe in your question the expected result.

Comment: oh sorry, I edited my code.

Comment: Yep. My answer should get you what you need. test it and see the results.

Comment: Yes, its solved.Thank you ..But i don't think its a right way to do so.

Comment: I think it's the right way to do it. No core hacks. That's the reason the secure urls are declared like that. So you can add them and change them. Unfortunately there is no way to remove url from the secure list. So changing one url to something that does not exist is the only way to go.

Comment: I accept, But i want to understand this scenario little bit more. How your solutions works, and how can i understand this thing.

Comment: @Manik. I already gave you an explanation. But here are some more words. There are 2 aspects. 1. Magento checks the urls that should be secured against all the urls from the config section that match this xpath: `config/frontend/secure_url`. 2. All the `config.xml` files are merged into one big xml file and that one is used. This approach allows you to add stuff to any xml node or override existing nodes. When loading a new `config.xml` if a node is already present in the big merged xml, that node is overwritten by the new one. This is what happens with the code I posted.